# Can't get it working: jQuery AJAX array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax, json

I've been experiencing a lot of trouble with my issue all afternoon. Endless searches on Google and SO haven't helped me unfortunately.

## The issue

I need to send an array to a PHP script using jQuery AJAX every 30 seconds. After constructing the array and sending it to the PHP file I seemingly get stuck. I can't seem to properly decode the array, it gives me *null* when I look at my console.

## The scripts

This is what I have so far. I am running jQuery 1.11.1 and PHP version 5.3.28 by the way.

**The jQuery/Ajax part**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});

    var interval = 30000;
    // var ids = ['1','2','3'];

    var ids = []; // This creates an array like this: ['1','2','3']
    $(".player").each(function() {
        ids.push(this.id);
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/fetchstatus.php",
            data: {"players" : ids},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }, interval);

});
```

**The PHP part (fetchstatus.php)**

```
if (isset($_POST["players"])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST["players"], true);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

## What I'd like

After decoding the JSON array I'd like to foreach loop it in order to get specific information from the rows in the database belonging to a certain id. In my case the rows 1, 2 and 3.
But I don't know if the decoded array is actually ready for looping. My experience with the console is minimal and I have no idea how to check if it's okay.

All the information belonging to the rows with those id's are then bundled into a new array, json encoded and then sent back in a success callback. Elements in the DOM are then altered using the information sent in this array.

---

Could someone tell me what exactly I am doing wrong/missing?
Perhaps the answer is easier than I think but I can't seem to find out myself.

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: Uhm, what does this have to do with AJAX, jQuery, and JSON? You're at the point where you have an array of numbers, and you actually need to interact with a database now, right?

Comment: @lxg The problem is I hardly ever worked with the console before and I have no idea how to see what the data looks like after it should be decoded. So I don't know if I am actually ready to interact with the database. Re-encoding the decoded array gives me null.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($data)` after decoding?

Comment: When I add `var_dump($data)` right after `$data = json_decode($_POST["players"], true);` I see nothing happening when I directly visit the file. But this is logical right? I am not "posting" anything when I visit directly.

Comment: Of course not. I would expect that you set up a test case where you can check if your script gets the data it expects.

Comment: @PeterdeLeeuw You can simply use a `<form action="../fetchstatus.php" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="players[]" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="players[]" value="2" /><input type="hidden" name="players[]" value="3" /><input type="submit" /></form>` for testing.

Comment: @lxg When I use the testing method provided by @algorhythm I get the following result for `var_dump($data)`: NULL null

Comment: I think your edit has made the problem more clear … at the moment you need to get JSON to the server; the DB stuff comes in a later stage. I think algorhythm and Bilal are on a good way, so let's see what comes up there.

Comment: you aren't sending JSON to server, default `contenType`being sent is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;`  ( see jQuery AJAX API) . Should have array as `$_POST["players"]` without json_decode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jQuery.ajax` option `dataType` is just for the servers answer. What type of anser are you expexting from 'fetchstatus.php'. And it's right, it's json. But what you send to this file via `post` method is not json.
You don't have to `json_decode` the `$_POST` data. Try outputting the POST data with `var_dump($_POST)`.

And what happens if 'players' is not given as parameter? Then no `JSON` is returning. Change your 'fetchstatus.php' like this:

```
$returningData = array(); // or 'false'

$data = @$_POST['players']; // @ supresses PHP notices if key 'players' is not defined

if (!empty($data) && is_array($data))
{
    var_dump($data); // dump the whole 'players' array

    foreach($data as $key => $value)
    {
        var_dump($value); // dump only one player id per iteration
        // do something with your database
    }

    $returningData = $data;
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($returningData);
```

**Using JSON:**
You can simply use your returning JSON data in jQuery, e.g. like this:

```
// replace ["1", "2", "3"] with the 'data' variable
jQuery.each(["1", "2", "3"], function( index, value ) {
    console.log( index + ": " + value );
});
```

And if you fill your `$data` variable on PHP side, use your player id as array key and an array with additional data as value e.g. this following structure:

```
$data = array(
    1 => array(
        // data from DB for player with ID 1
    ),
    2 => array(
        // data from DB for player with ID 2
    ),
    ...
);

// [...]
echo json_decode($data);
```

Comment: When I use your testing method mentioned earlier I get the following var_dump: array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" } ["1","2","3"]. When I remove the `var_dump()` statement I see the following in my Console every 30 seconds: ["1", "2", "3"].
Even though this seems to be working, am I not making mistakes with JSON?

Comment: No JSON is a good choice and simple to use. You can nearly convert every object to JSON and directly access it later with JavaScript or better jQuery. What do you mean?

Comment: Because I was convinced I sent JSON while it wasn't JSON at all haha. Hence the fact I tried to `json_decode()` the data sent to fetchstatus.php. This makes me doubt I did it all the right way now, even though your answer seems to be the fix for my issue. Perhaps it's smarter to do everything by JSON?

Comment: Ah I noticed you just edited your post for an all JSON solution. I'll check it out now.

Comment: I depends on your context, if you are just delivering data, then JSON is pretty nice, because when the data was send to the client, it is simply accessable. But sometimes you need generated HTML to directly show it e.g. via `jQuery($selector).load(url)` or your data is already present in XML, then you could think about another `dataType`. In your case I would prefer JSON.

Comment: Ah, and for JSON there are so many pretty tools, e.g. a formatter/validator http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com or the PHP Online functions to test the result of e.g. `json_encode` http://www.functions-online.com/search.html?cosearch=json&costart=1

Comment: I managed to foreach loop the array, retrieve database data per element in the array and create a brand new multidimensional array with the newly retrieved data. Now all I have to do is json_encode() the new multidimensional array and make jQuery handle it properly; my new challenge.

Answer (score 1):

What I suspect is that the data posted is not in the proper JSON format. You need to use `JSON.stringify()` to encode an array in javascript. [Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ifandelse/6Yj5h/) of building JSON.

In JS you can use `console.log('something');` to see the output in browser console window. To see posted data in php you can do `echo '<pre>'; print_r($someArrayOrObjectOrAnything); die();`.

`print_r` prints human-readable information about a variable

So in your case use `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);` to see if something is actually posted or not.

Comment: Should I try to JSON.stringify() the data attribute in the AJAX call? Like: data: JSON.stringify({"players" : ids}),. I have seen this before but I've also seen succesful implementations without stringify.

Comment: Do not change anything and tell me what you get when you `print_r($_POST)`? Copy and paste.

Comment: I added `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);` to the fetchstatus.php file outside the isset() statement. When I visit this file directly all I see is this:

`Array
(
)`

Comment: If you visit your file directly you don't have any POST-parameters... Have a look in your browsers web inspector to see what your `print_r` gives you an AJAX calls.

Comment: When I use your testing method that @algorhythm mentioned earlier, I get the following result when using `echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);` outside the isset() statement: null<pre>Array
(
    [players] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)

Comment: Yeah, that's good. Now you have your array which can be iterated with a loop. And then make your DB call.

Comment: Sorry, I slept and couldn't follow up. Now it shows that you don't need to `json_decode` in your php file just use the array in `foreach` loop. Like this `foreach($_POST['players'] as $value)` and `$value` will be your desired `id` that you want.